# Why is React useeffect not updated when props are destructured

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state, use-effect

I have had some issues with my props not updating correctly when they are destructorized in combination with useEffect dependencies. I now know how I can fix the issue but I do not understand why it happens.

The example below does not work properly and does not show changes when the props changes.

```js
const Devices = ({ apis }) => {
  const [ availableApis, _setAvailableApis ] = useState([])
  const availableApisRef = useRef( availableApis )
  const setAvailableApis = v => {
    availableApisRef.current = v
    _setAvailableApis( v )
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    let availableApis = []

    apis.forEach( v => {
      console.log(v)
      if( v.available === true )
      {
        availableApis.push( v )
      }
    })

    console.log(availableApis)

    setAvailableApis( availableApis )
  }, [ apis ])

  return <somecomponent key={v.name} />
}
```

If I replace `const Devices = ({ apis }) => {` with `const Devices = props => {`
and replace `}, [ apis ])` with `}, [ props ])` the changes are rendered.

I thought this would have the same effect, but it does not.

**Note:** This problem does not occur when useEffect effect is not used, but the variable is simply used in a component.

```js
const ApiStatus = ({ available, apiName, openLogin }) => {
  return (
    <StatusContainer onClick={openLogin}  available={available}>
      <p> { apiName } - { available ? "Beschikbaar" : "Uitgelogd" } </p>
    </StatusContainer>
  )
}
```

Comment: Just for what it's worth, the word is "destructured" (removed from a structure).

Comment: I've answered the question you actually asked below, but I suspect you may have a more fundamental underlying question (the [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). What about your code isn't working correctly when `apis` is the only dependency of the effect? The code looks like that's the correct set of dependencies. Separately, what's the purpose of the ref holding the same thing you have in state? That seems problematic.

Answer (score 1):

> If I replace `const Devices = ({ apis }) => {` with `const Devices = props => {` and `replace }, [ apis ])` with `}, [ props ])` the changes are rendered.

Those are **very** different things. The first re-runs the effect when `apis` changes, ignoring any other changes. The second re-runs the effect any time `props`, the object, changes. (And I think you get a new object [though possibly with the same contents] on **every** render of the child component, so you probably don't want that.)

If you accept `props` rather than `{apis}`, the equivalent dependency array for `useEffect` is `[props.apis]`.

Looking at the code of your effect, it looks like it depends on `apis` and not on other props, so it makes sense for the dependency array to be `[apis]` (or `[props.apis]` if you don't destructure).

Comment: Maybe the part you qouted was confusing, I was using `[apis]` when I did destructure.
So `({apis}) => {}` with `[apis]` as the dependency. Removing `useRef()` did not change the situtation and thus was indeed over complicating the code. However when adding `[props.apis]` (the argument of the function is not destructored) like you suggested acts the same as the method mentioned at the start of this comment. 
I normally write class components but I thought I would step a bit of my comfort zone for this project and try functional components.

Comment: @controlol - Yes, that was clear. You were using `[apis]` as the deps array when you were destructuring, and `[props]` as the deps array when you weren't. Those are very different. The equivalent to the first one if you don't destructure is `[props.apis]`, as I said above. (But the destructuring is just fine, I'd keep doing it.)